# CTE in recursive CTE to access recursive part multiple times

Tags: mysql, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the following query that runs fine under postgres and I hope to make it work on MySQL as well:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dependent(id) AS (
    SELECT id FROM data_category WHERE id = :cat
UNION (
    WITH parents AS ( SELECT * FROM dependent)
        SELECT child_id AS id
        FROM data_category_1 dc 
        INNER JOIN parents ON dc.id = parents.id
      UNION
        SELECT child_id AS id
        FROM data_category_2 dc 
        INNER JOIN parents ON dc.id = parents.id
    )
)
SELECT id from dependent
```

I get a quite helpful error message:
`Error : In recursive query block of Recursive Common Table Expression 'dependent', the recursive table must be referenced only once, and not in any subquery`

The problem seem to be the CTE inside the recursive part. I need this because I have to access the recursive part `parents` multiple times. Under postgres this does work fine.